# How do I search through the names of my stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a large number of stored procedures in my database, and I would like to see if one of those would accomplish my task before I write a new one. How would I search through just the names of the existing stored procedures (as opposed to the contents)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.procedures WHERE name LIKE '%search_text%';
```

SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '%search_text%' AND xtype = 'P';
```

Another good idea is to establish a sensible naming schema. You shouldn't have to search at all if your naming convention is consistent and logical.

Comment: +1 for a sensible naming schema. Unfortunately, this isn't always an [immediate] option. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM syscomments
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(id)
LIKE '%search_text%'
```

Comment: syscomments is a backward-compatibility view. There are much more efficient ways to do this on SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005** and newer, try to avoid using the *old-style* `sysXXXX` catalog views. Instead, use the views in the `sys` schema - e.g. `sys.procedures` for stored procedures.

Comment: Also why are you posting multiple answers to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  name
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   type = 'P'
        AND name LIKE '%search_text%'
```

Comment: `sys.procedures` would be more focused - no need to specify a `type = 'P'` - it lists only procedures....

Answer (score -1):

The above methods all work great but an easier approach is to download a copy of SQL Search from Red Gate. It's a free utility that plugs into SSMS and allows you to search on all objects throughout the entire server.

Comment: While it is a useful utility, it seems overkill for just finding stored procedure names.

Comment: (P.S. I wasn't the one who down-voted. I think it's a useful utility in general, just not necessary to solve this specific problem. One should be versed in the catalog views and this is very easy to solve using them alone.)

Comment: Agreed...I just find the utility a great help for day to day admin and tend to use it for everything once installed